# Counting Problem Discrete Math: How many DNA strings of length $6$ have exactly two thymine (T) nucleotides?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am struggling on this question.

DNA = Four Nucleotides (C,G,A,T)
Cytosine
Guanine
Adenine
Thymine

How many DNA strings of length $6$ have exactly two (T) thymine nucleotides?

Ex: CTATAG,GGGTTG,TAAATG not CAAATG nor CTGTTG?

I am not sure how to go about solving the problem. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: First fix the two thymines in the string. This can be done by choosing $2$ positions out of $6$. Then, in the rest of the positions, fill anything but thymine. This is done in three ways for each of four slots. Can you figure it out now?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг: You should write that as an answer.

Comment: Does it mean that the answer is 1215 ways?

Answer (score 1):

Choose $2$ out of $6$ places for the Ts: $\binom62=15$.

Fill the remaining $4$ places with any of the other $3$ letters: $3^4=81$.

The answer is therefore $15\cdot81=1215$.

Answer (score 1):

First, fix the two positions in the string where you want to put thymines. This is done in $\binom 62 = 15$ ways.

Next, in the remaining four positions any one of adenine, cytosine and guanine can come. Since these are independent of each other, the number of ways to make this happen is $3 ^ 4=81$ (4 slots, 3 choices for each slot).

So the answer is $81 \times 15 = 1215$ ways.